# R Function to create "blended" list by joining on matching elements?

Tags: r, list, mapping

Say I have a list of int vectors that looks like:

```
1: {1,4,5}
2:{2}
3:{2,3}
4:{4,5}
5:{5}
```

I want to receive a version of this list where all common items are shared between all members, like so:

```
1: {1,4,5}
2: {2,3}
3: {2,3}
4: {1,4,5}
5: {1,4,5}
```

I have managed it with for loops by doing a forward- and backward-pass, but it takes a long time when there's a lot of members.

```
#exchange information
        for(i in 1:nrow(current_set)){
            if(verbose){cat(paste("Processing Set", i))}
            #first pass
            first_ident = identity_mapper[[current_set[i,1]]]
            second_ident = identity_mapper[[current_set[i,2]]]

            identity_mapper[[current_set[i,1]]] = c(first_ident, second_ident)
            identity_mapper[[current_set[i,2]]] = c(second_ident, first_ident)

            #removes all in-component connections
            df_out = df_out[which(!(df_out[,1] %in% identity_mapper[[current_set[i,1]]] &
                                        df_out[,2] %in% identity_mapper[[current_set[i,1]]])),]
            #second passes
            for(j in 1:length(identity_mapper)){
                if(verbose){cat(paste("Second Pass", j, "\n"))}
                current_members = identity_mapper[[j]]
                for(k in current_members){
                    identity_mapper[[k]] = unique(append(identity_mapper[[k]], current_members))
                }
            }
        }
```

Works, but slow. current_set is a set of valid observations of the form x,y. df_out is the set of all observations. identity mapper is the list of the aforementioned format.

Comment: This is not reproducible. Could you add example data using `dput()` and also add everything such that the snippet can be executed without errors, e.g. adding `identity_mapper`.